# SpringBoot in Pivotal Cloud Issue

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy the SpringBoot Restful application in Pivotal Cloud factory.
My JDK 1.8 and using Maven. 
Tried the below Sample application from pivotal:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Maven build is successful with the jar file generated at target folder.

I have added manifest.yml at the pom.xml file location as below.

```
---
applications:
- name: rest-mini
  buildpack: https://github.com/gratiartis/java-buildpack
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  host: rest-mini
  domain: cfapps.io
  path: target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
```

Logged into pivotal web service account and trying to push it as

"cf push" and getting the below error. Please advice. thanks

```
    2016-05-16T01:48:49.88+0800 [API/1]      OUT Created app with guid 281c1f5f-235d-497a-8d1a-2d396ccc48c3
2016-05-16T01:48:58.16+0800 [API/3]      OUT Updated app with guid 281c1f5f-235d-497a-8d1a-2d396ccc48c3 ({"route"=>"ed5e6122-f52a-4562-9293-09da16281fba"})
2016-05-16T01:49:31.68+0800 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 281c1f5f-235d-497a-8d1a-2d396ccc48c3 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-05-16T01:49:31.98+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Creating container
2016-05-16T01:49:32.45+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Successfully created container
2016-05-16T01:49:32.45+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Downloading app package...
2016-05-16T01:49:33.09+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded app package (11.5M)
2016-05-16T01:49:33.09+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Staging...
2016-05-16T01:49:33.80+0800 [STG/0]      ERR /tmp/buildpacks/38ac912092c32b9507ea7ac5fc033650/lib/java_buildpack/component/versioned_dependency_component.rb:68: warning: circular argument reference - jar_name
2016-05-16T01:49:34.19+0800 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Java Buildpack Version: 717d8bf | https://github.com/gratiartis/java-buildpack#717d8bf
2016-05-16T01:49:35.45+0800 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto.tar.gz (1.0s)
2016-05-16T01:49:36.61+0800 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.1s)
2016-05-16T01:49:36.71+0800 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
**2016-05-16T01:49:36.71+0800 [STG/0]      ERR [Buildpack]                      ERROR Compile failed with exception #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String>**
2016-05-16T01:49:36.71+0800 [STG/0]      ERR no implicit conversion of nil into String
2016-05-16T01:49:36.72+0800 [STG/0]      ERR Failed to compile droplet
2016-05-16T01:49:36.73+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Exit status 223
2016-05-16T01:49:36.73+0800 [STG/0]      ERR Staging failed: Exited with status 223
2016-05-16T01:49:36.83+0800 [API/3]      ERR Failed to stage application: staging failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack` official CF buildpack.

The one you are using seems outdated, it was last updated on Sep 25, 2014.
Also assign more memory `memory: 256M or 512M`, 128M might work as well.

Comment: Thanks, sanjay for your response. Let me check and update the status.

Comment: I have tried and working fine..thanks a lot for your response

Comment: @Ahmed please accept if this answers your question and may be upvote if u like ;)

Comment: @SanjayRawat - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774751/spring-cloud-foundry-issue-223 ?